# File Not Found Error:[WinError 2] Python Directory Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error when I try to delete some files from my directory. When I delete the file I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37-32/deletefiles.py", line 36, in <module>
    os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:'C:/*****/*****/*****/****\\3047InforEmpData04012020082901.csv'
```

The program is

```
path = r"C:/*****/*****/*****/"
folder_list = ["ftpuser_AMC", 
 "ftpuser_APM","ftpuser_BAL","ftpuser_BBD","ftpuser_BBW","ftpuser_BEM","ftpuser_BGM",               
 "ftpuser_gah","ftpuser_jac","ftpuser_ker","ftpuser_mer","ftpuser_mhv","ftpuser_sop","ftpuser_trg",
 "ftpuser_win","ftpuser_WSG"]

current_time = time.time()
lst_folder_list = []
if os.path.exists(path):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.split(root)[-1] in folder_list:
        lst_folder_list.append(root)
else:
   print("Error Path Doesn't Exist!!!!!!!!!!!!")

# alternatively you could provide the listof folderpaths directly of course
for folder_path in lst_folder_list:

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
        file_status = os.stat(full_path)
        #print(full_path)

        if root.endswith("EightFiles"):
            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 1:
                print("% s has been removed successfully 7 days" % full_path)  
                os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
        
        if root.endswith("InforFiles"):
            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 7:
                print("% s has been removed successfully 7 days" % full_path)  
                os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
        
        if root.endswith("FilesSent"):
            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 7:
                print("% s has been removed successfully 7 days" % full_path)  
                os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))

        if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 21:
                print("% s has been removed successfully 21 days" % full_path)  
                os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
```

Comment: Try printing the path, then accessing it via the Files Explorer. Make sure that the path is correct, and that the program has permissions to delete it.

Comment: When you do `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):` the full path to each file in files is `os.path.join(root, file)` and not `os.path.join(folder_path,file)` except for the first iteration.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. You've got a `for folder_path in lst_folder_list:` that doesn't have a body but then you use `folder_path` in following `for` loop instead of `for root, dirs, files ...`. It seems like you've just pasted together two different ways of doing the enumeration. Remove one - its not needed here - and stick with a single bit of running code.

Comment: The traceback says line 36 but that doesn't align with the code you've posted. You have that same line of code in several places so we have to guess which one it is. That's why its important to post the real code that had the error.

Comment: Notice that with `if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 21:` you attempt to delete files even if they were delted in the one of the `if` 's above. That is likely your problem.

Comment: Those are two different roots though right? @tdelaney

Comment: @tdelaney how could I fix this?

Comment: Maybe its just a problem with the indentation of that for loop.I think the problem is that a file can match two conditions (for intstance, it ends with "EightFiles" and is 21 days old) and so you unlink it twice. You fix that by using `elif` instead of `if`. And you can slim down that code a bit... I'll post that as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file can meet 2 conditions in your `if` statements (for instance, name ends with "EightFiles" and is 21 days old) which means the unlink will be attempted twice. The solution is to use `elif` clauses that only run if all previous clauses have not.

```
if thing:
    do work
elif other thing:
    do other work
...
```

These if's repeat code so its worth considering a way to eliminate that. You could put name/time-to-live values into a list and loop through them. Focusing on just that part,

```
# time to live in days when files end with various values
root_endswith_ttl = [("", 21), ("EightFiles", 1), ("InforFiles", 7),
    ("FilesSent", 7)] 

current_time = time.time()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
        delta = (current_time - os.stat(full_path).st_mtime)//86400
        for name, ttl in root_endswith_ttl:
            if delta >= ttl and root.endswith(name):
                os.unlink(full_path)
                print("% s has been removed successfully %i days" 
                        % (full_path, ttl))
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Directory Path
path = r"C:/****/*****/LocalUser/"

# Current Time of the day
current_time = time.time()

if os.path.exists(path):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
        file_status = os.stat(full_path)
        #print(full_path)
        print(file)
        if root.endswith("EightFiles") or root.endswith("InforFiles") or 
            root.endswith("FilesSent"):
            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 7:
                #os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
                os.unlink(file)
                print("% s has been removed successfully 7 days" % full_path)  
        else:
            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= 21: 
                #os.unlink(os.path.join(folder_path,file))
                os.unlink(file)
                print("% s has been removed successfully 21 days" % full_path) 
else:
    print("Error Path Doesn't Exist!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: This is my updated code with the same error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37-32/deletefiles.py", line 29, in <module>
    os.unlink(file)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '1733InforEmpData04012020170219.csv'  @tdelaney

Comment: It should be `os.unlink(full_path)`